# qsort on struct with number and char, sort on number first and then sort on alphabet with same number

Tags: c, qsort

Would like to qsort on struct with number and char, sort on number first and then sort on alphabet with same number
Here is the struct i have

```
typedef struct{
    char word[101];
    int freq;
}WordArray;
```

Here is the logic I followed: Sort on freq first ()

```
int cmpffunc (const void * a, const void * b)
{
    WordArray *WordArrayA = (WordArray *)a;
    WordArray *WordArrayB = (WordArray *)b;
    return ( WordArrayB->freq - WordArrayA->freq );
}
qsort(array, arrayLength, sizeof(WordArray), cmpffunc);
```

Which works fine, then I tried to sort on the alphabet with same freq number. Here is the thing I tried but non of them work as expected:

```
int cmpwfunc (const void * a, const void * b)
{
    WordArray *A = (WordArray *)a;
    WordArray *B = (WordArray *)b;
    if (A->freq == B->freq){
        return strcmp(A->word,B->word);
    }
    else{
        return -1;
    }
}
qsort(array, arrayLength, sizeof(WordArray), cmpwfunc);
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't seem your second function differentiates between `A->freq > B->freq` and `A->freq < B->freq`

Comment: You can put both ways of sorting in the same comparsion function. If `freq` is unequal return that result. Otherwise return the string comparison result. Beware of using `WordArrayB->freq - WordArrayA->freq` for the integer comparison, sooner or later you'll do this and an overflow will return the wrong result.  Make the explicit comparisons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your second version is when `A->freq` and `B->freq` are **not** equal. In that case you can't just `return -1`. In that case you need to compare 
`A->freq` and `B->freq` like you did in the first function. So...

Change

```
else{
    return -1;
}
```

to

```
return ( B->freq - A->freq );
```

Or better - change it to

```
if ( B->freq > A->freq ) return 1;
return -1;
```

Comment: Note: `B->freq - A->freq` has the disadvantaged of potential `int` overflow.  The answer's later solution is correct.